# Is the path.scope.bindings only contains variables that in source code but not dynamic insert at babel transforming?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-plugin

I'm trying to insert an import statement when transpiling my code with babel plugin. The statement might be dynamically inserted multiple times, so I have to make sure it don't be inserted before.

I used to `path.scope.hasOwnBinding` and `path.scope.hasBinding` for making sure they don't collide with existing ones, but it was not working for a dynamic insert variable.

```js
const conditions = ['view', 'text'];
function Plugin({types: t, template}) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      ImportDeclaration(path, state) {
        var node = path.node;
        var sourceValue = node.source.value;

        conditions.forEach(item => {
          if (name === sourceValue) {
            // multi insert
            if (!path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp") && !path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")) {
              const myImport = template(`import AsyncComp from "../src/";`, { sourceType: "module" });
              path.insertAfter(myImport());
            }
            if (path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp")) {
              // never execute
            }
            if (path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")) {
              // never execute
            }

          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect they can detect the variable that I'm inserted before, but encountered error message is `Duplicate declaration AsyncComp`

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong

```
if (!path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp") || path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")) {
```

is `!path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp")` **OR** `path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")`, so you insert `import` clause when `path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")` returns true

You need one of the following:

```
if (!(path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp") || path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp"))) {
```

or

```
if (!path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp") && !path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is my problem that copy wrong. I modify it but still not work.

Comment: You changed to `!path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp") || !path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")`, so if `path.scope.hasOwnBinding("AsyncComp")` is false it's satisfied without checking `path.scope.hasBinding("AsyncComp")`